# Como, após uma requisição POST, inserir valores em uma outra tabela de forma automatica com o Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Boa noite!
Estou com a seguinte questão:
Tenho 3 tabelas (Alunos, EtapaSala, Sala)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem perceber o EtapaSala é uma tabela de ligação entre o aluno e a sala.
Eu estou utilizando a estrutura MVC com Entity Framework, já fiz o crud das 3 tabelas e tudo funciona corretamente.
O problema é que eu não queria ter que ir na View de EtapaSala para vincular um aluno na sua sala em determinada etapa e nem colocar um dropdown no cadastro do aluno para tal, eu gostaria de fazer isso de forma automática no momento em que fizesse a requisição POST do aluno, vincular ele à uma sala na etapa 1 e outra sala na etapa 2.

Segue o código do método POST de AlunosController:

```
// POST: Alunos/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("IdAluno,Nome,Sobrenome")] Aluno aluno)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(aluno);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(aluno);
    }
```

Model de EtapaSala:

```
public partial class EtapaSala
{ 

    public int IdEtapa { get; set; }
    public int? Etapa { get; set; }
    public int? IdAluno { get; set; }
    public int? IdSala { get; set; }

    public virtual Aluno IdAlunoNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual Sala IdSalaNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: se as tabelas estiverem relacionadas corretamente no código, o EF vai inserir em cascasta, nas 3 tabelas se for preciso

Comment: Como assim? Acho que vc não entendeu a pergunta, as tabelas estao relacionadas, tanto que quando vou na view EtapaSala tem os ids dos alunos e das salas pra escolher e cadastrar normalmente, mas não é isso que quero, queria ao criar o Aluno, ja fazer o insert na EtapaSala Automaticamente, sem precisar ir em nenhuma tela ou selecionar nd no cadastro do aluno.

Comment: Primeiro na tela de cadastro de Aluno tem que ter mais essa informação da Sala! no próprio request tem que esse valor ou valores de salas, ao clicar no botão no código insere o aluno e depois a sala que assim o pertence. Tem um coisa desnecessária o id Etapa só as duas chaves são necessárias.

Comment: acho que você quem não entendeu...se está tudo relacionado e direito no EF só preencher todos os objetos e fazer um único save no banco (ApplyChanges). Se está relacionado deve ter `Aluno.EtapaSala` e em `EtapaSala.Sala`, só setar todos os valores e inserir de uma unica vez, ou vir tudo preenchido como o @novic comentou

Comment: Desculpe Ricardo, não tinha entendido mesmo, obrigado! Realmente então minha modelagem tem alguns erros então certo? como o novic mencionou, o id da etapa é desnecessário e eu obrigatóriamente preciso ter um campo sala em alunos, mas e o campo etapa? porque serão duas etapas  e de uma etapa pra outra, metade de uma sala vai trocar de lugar com a outra, então precisaria já estar pré-registrado as salas que o cada aluno vai estar em cada etapa.

Comment: Acredito que na sua modelagem faltou incluir o IDEtapa como esta na classe. Mas seria necessário rever sua modelagem para que criar este processo.